# Add vi on Busybox which is trimmed down

Tags: linux, embedded, busybox, telnet

I have a smart energy plug which is running Busybox and works over Wifi to my local LAN. I can telnet into it, but lack crucial binaries like vi. I'd like to add a few scripts to the device, but cannot at this moment. There is however a webserver running on it that serves ASP pages for config. Could something be done with that?
Below some more information about what's available. Ideally, I'd like to extend Busybox with the binaries that I need.

```
# uname -a
Linux (none) 2.6.21 #324 Mon Aug 25 16:53:40 CST 2014 mips unknown

# /bin/busybox
BusyBox v1.12.1 (2014-07-31 06:32:52 CEST) multi-call binary
Copyright (C) 1998-2008 Erik Andersen, Rob Landley, Denys Vlasenko
and others. Licensed under GPLv2.
See source distribution for full notice.

Currently defined functions:
        [, [[, ash, brctl, cat, chmod, chpasswd, cp, crond, date, dd, df,
        du, echo, expr, free, grep, halt, ifconfig, init, init, insmod, kill,
        killall, login, ls, lsmod, mkdir, mknod, mount, ping, poweroff, printf,
        ps, pwd, reboot, rm, rmmod, route, sed, sh, sleep, syslogd, telnetd,
        test, tftp, top, touch, tr, udhcpc, udhcpd, umount, uname, uptime,
        vconfig, wc

# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   futexfs
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devpts
nodev   ramfs
nodev   jffs2

# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /var type ramfs (rw)
none on /etc type ramfs (rw)
none on /tmp type ramfs (rw)
none on /media type ramfs (rw)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)

# df
Filesystem           1k-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
```

Comment: How much free space do you have on that thing (your df output is somehow empty)? You can download precompiled busybox with (almost) all applets enabled directly from the busybox site.

Answer (score 2):

You can can transfer files using `tftp`. With it you can transfer various tools on your device, including another `busybox` which has `vi` and other utilities you need in it (check `/proc/cpuinfo` for the architecture).

Should there be no working `busybox` with `vi` for your architecture you can try to compile it yourself (preferably statically linked to `uClibc`) using Buildroot (https://buildroot.org/) or Crosstools-NG (http://crosstool-ng.org/) as a toolchain or like +Gilles pointed out have a look at: http://packages.debian.org/sid/busybox-static (unpack it using `ar vx`).

Comment: You can get a statically-linked `busybox` with most features enabled for most architectures [from debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/busybox-static).